# Critique: music and graphics company logo

Tags: logo, critique, marketing

This is the logo I designed for my Music and Graphics Productions Company, http://www.psychoproductions.net. Can you please review, and provide feedback. Is this logo well branded for the type of company? Does it draw attention?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your font treatment is pulling in the same direction as your graphic skull, for two reasons:

1. "Plaza" is Art Deco era ([google](https://www.google.com.au/?gws_rd=ssl#q=art%20deco%20font), [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_Deco)) and brings that baggage with it.
2. Both layouts are symmetrical – which contrasts with the connotation of "Psycho". Maybe something more unbalanced would be more striking?

Answer (score 1):

The dots are the fattest items in the picture and they don't really mean anything. If you have a budget for ink it's like you spent it all on dots and didn't have anything left over for skull.

If the skull is supposed to be scary then having an upside down heart for a nose and toothpicks for teeth is not scary. I guess it's kind of like you need to decide if this is cute or not, and if it's cute then make it more cute...if it's scary then make it more scary.

But I listened and the music doesn't sound like heavy metal or anything. Maybe you should let someone who isn't you make a drawing while listening to the music. Do you really need a "logo" in the first place? Bands don't have logos, usually.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. To give some background, this brand does not represent a band, it is a production company. I believe a company always warrants a logo. My goal was to be more appealing to the edginess and quality of the music the company produces. Now there is a band within the company, sort of a project within a project, but that band has its own set of images.

Comment: That might confuse people. Maybe you should not have a band and a production company with the same name. I think that something about bands is that they change their styles over time (at least some do) and that's why I said that having a logo is kind of not really a band thing.

Comment: Also, I don't know what you use, but it sounds like very MIDI stuff. If you use something like Fruityloops (or Ableton if you have $) then the instruments are a bit better, you could run those same songs through it and it would sound less old.